# Over-voltage protection for mini-computer

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, robotics, over-voltage-protection

I am working on a mobile robot and have damaged 2 RPis as a result of what appears to be a transient over-voltage situation. Please see the attached drawing of the basic setup. The failure is not repeatable so its tricky to figure out what exactly is causing it (after the first failure, I changed the DC-DC converter). Is there anything that appears to be missing? The only common action between the two failures I can recall is the e-stop button is used. The motor controller from Roboteq (FBL2360) allows regeneration but it has been capped at 35V which the DC-DC converter is able to handle. These over-voltage situations also damage the USB devices connected to the RPis and there are some expensive components so any recommendations to further protect those?
Here's the [DC-DC converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J3MHRNO)

[image]

Comment: Massive Zener? TVS? Did you try to capture with a scope what kind of transients do you have?

Comment: You haven't shown peripheral connections (like USB, etc) connected to PI...if these are powered while PI is un-powered, you can run into CMOS latch-up problems. Ensure that all peripherals power up and power down at the same time.

Comment: Is the DC/DC converter a simple buck regulator or is it fully isolated?  Place a protection diode across the motor.  Is the diode in you sch across the coil or the contacts?

Comment: @AliChen thanks for the TVS recommendation. Since this is not a repeatable error, I haven't been able to capture it on a scope.

Comment: @glen_geek The peripherals draw power from the Pi so they should all the on at the same time

Comment: @AnalogKid The first regulator was just a buck converter and I'm guessing the second one is too since it does not explicitly say it is an isolator (I provided the link to it in my description). What benefit would the isolator provide? Current flows in both directions (to and from the motor) so how would the protection diode be set in this case? The diode I've shown is across the coil for flyback.

Comment: You don't need to wait until your other PIs is fried. Just hook up a scope and toggle your button several times, then tell us what you see.

Comment: @AliChen I will try this during the weekend when I'm back on the field.

Comment: [This is a minicomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicomputer)

Comment: Please show pictures of your setup. There is most likely some coupling happening somewhere. Is the battery "-" connected to the chassis? How are the USB devices grounded? Is any   conductive part of your rPi+devices system (cables, enclosures, etc, anything) making contact with the chassis, or running near the high current wires? I suspect there is a connection somewhere that is not shown on your schematic.

Comment: Also the buck converter looks a bit like cheap junk...

Comment: @peufeu I'll be able to get pictures in a couple days. The chassis is steel but it completely powder coated. The battery "-" is not connected to the chassis and neither are any other devices. The diagram I have above is simplified - the Pi is at the front of the chassis and there are several IO wires from it (buttons/lights) running to the back. The contactor wire runs in parallel with these IO wires and I'm seeing that that is probably a bad idea. The motor wires also come within 5cm of the IO wires at some point. Could these be the culprits?

Comment: @peufeu I'm willing to get a better DC-DC if there are advantages to doing so. Any recommendations?

Comment: The worst case is usually when someone "tidies up the wiring" and neatly bundles the high-current ones with the low-power sensitive stuff... Anyway. Either it was an overvoltage, and the buck converter killed the Pi, but the Buck magically survived (it did, right? how would it destroy the Pi and still live?... not impossible, but not likely) or a USB cable caught some very strong EMI from nearby high current wire which fried the USB device and the rPi... could be both...

Comment: @peufeu yes the buck converter survived in both cases. I've implemented better cable separation so hopefully that does it. You asked earlier if the chassis is connected to ground. Seems like I should be avoiding that to guard against unexpected current paths?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the relay interrupts the motor current, 20 amperes, in 20 nanoseconds.

Suppose there is a wire running from the relay to the motor controller, and that wire couples into the RPi regulated power; the wiring between regulator and RPI forms a loop with VDD and RTN.  <- EDIT

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRHbKM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose the distance from wire to loop is 1cm. Suppose the loop area is 1cm by 10cm (4"). What voltage is induced, on top of the regulated RPi VDD?

$$Vinduce = [MU0 * MUr * Area/(2 * pi * Distance)] / dI/dT$$

What is the induced voltage? anything higher than 1 volt transient is bad news.
Now insert value for MU0 of 4 * pi * 1e-7

Vinduce = 2e-7 * area/distance * dI/dT

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 1cm*10cm/1cm * 1amp/nanosecond

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 10cm * 10^+9 amp/second = 2e-7 * 0.1 * 1e+9

Vinduce = 2e+1 = 20 volts induced

---

To avoid this (e.g. reduce the induced voltage from 20 volts to 0.2 volts),

(1) keep the MCU PCB a meter away from the high-current fast-off motor wires (hot and return wires).

(2) place a steel plate adjacent to the MCU PCB, insulated to prevent shorts; have the plate be larger than the MCU PCB

(3) insert a PI filter (C-L-C) at the MCU PCB, as shown

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLVa0m.png)</sup>

The one Ohm across inductor is for dampening. Rdampen = sqrt(L/C) =sqrt(1mh/0.1mF) = sqrt(100 = 3.16 ohms ideal. The 1 ohm is over dampening.

Comment: I'm still not clear on why extra voltage is induced here at all. What do you mean by 'a loop with VDD and RTN'? I think I need some more background on where the loop is and why it is inducing extra voltage. How would you recommend this gets fixed?

Comment: thanks for the recommendations. So I'm guessing the 24V loop running from the battery to the DC-DC should also be kept away from the current switching wires or is that unecessary since they run at the thesame voltage?